# What's the perl equivalent to a C file-scope variable, and how to use it in a sub?

Tags: perl

Trying to understand packages, `local`, `my`, and references in perl.  Consider the following script...

```
package z;
$x = 5;

sub q() { return $z::x };

printf "q() .. %d\n", q();

my $xr = \$x;

my $x = 7;

printf "xr .. %d\n",$$xr;

$$xr = 9;

printf "x .. %d\n", $x;

$$xr = 11;

printf "q() .. %d\n", q();
```

I expect each of the invocations of `q()` to return a number, but I'm not sure what they should return.  Instead I get the following output...

```
q() .. 0
Argument "" isn't numeric in printf at src/demo/multi_my.pl line 8.
xr .. 5
x .. 7
q() .. 0
Argument "" isn't numeric in printf at src/demo/multi_my.pl line 22.
```

Comment: `q()` is another way of writing `''`. Use a different sub name.

Comment: And don't use [prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) unless you know what they're for and have a good reason to use them. `sub foo() { }` should be `sub foo { }`.

Comment: You should add `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` to the top of your program to get a realistic idea of Perl's behaviour, as you will be adding them to every other program that you write.

Answer (score 4):

`q()` is another way of writing `''`. That's why `q()` is returning an empty string. Use a different name for your sub.

---

`my` declares a lexically-scoped variable. These are usually created by curlies, but the file is also a lexical scope. So if you want a variable scoped to a file, use `my $x;` outside of any curlies.

---

The first `$x` you access is globally-scoped; it's visible as `$z::x` throughout the program.